# Parse SOAP XML in Oracle with example

Tags: xml, oracle, soap

Below is a typical SOAP request in table 'external'.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<settleResponse xmlns="urn:ABC">
 <settleReturn xmlns="">
  <message>Missing first name</message>
  <errorCode>INVALID_ACC</errorCode>
  <customData>offendingTransactionID=12345678</customData>
  <divisionRequestID xsi:nil="true"/>
  <status>Failed</status>
 </settleReturn>
</settleResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to retrieve parameters errorCode, status... and save them in to a DB table. How can I do that?

Comment: Above SOAP XML is inside 'message' column with datatype as CLOB in the table 'external'.

Comment: @apc : Please look into this request.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the node contents with `XMLQUERY`:

```
select xmlquery('declare namespace soapenv = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
      declare namespace urn = "urn:ABC";
      /soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/urn:settleResponse/settleReturn/message/text()'
    passing XMLType(message)
    returning content) as message,
  xmlquery('declare namespace soapenv = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
      declare namespace urn = "urn:ABC";
      /soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/urn:settleResponse/settleReturn/errorCode/text()'
    passing XMLType(message)
    returning content) as errorCode,
  xmlquery('declare namespace soapenv = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
      declare namespace urn = "urn:ABC";
      /soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/urn:settleResponse/settleReturn/status/text()'
    passing XMLType(message)
    returning content) as status
from external;

MESSAGE              ERRORCODE            STATUS   
-------------------- -------------------- ----------
Missing first name   INVALID_ACC          Failed
```

Or perhaps more simply, particularly if you have multiple messages to handle, with `XMLTABLE`:

```
select x.*
from external ext
cross join xmltable(
  xmlnamespaces('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as  "soapenv",
    'urn:ABC' as "urn"),
  '/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/urn:settleResponse/settleReturn'
  passing XMLType(ext.message)
  columns message varchar2(20) path 'message',
    errorCode varchar2(20) path 'errorCode',
    status varchar2(10) path 'status'
) x;

MESSAGE              ERRORCODE            STATUS   
-------------------- -------------------- ----------
Missing first name   INVALID_ACC          Failed
```

In both cases you need to specify the namespaces, and the syntax is different. [Read more about using these functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm).

You can insert those directly into another table with `insert into some_table (x, y, z) select ...`.