# ORACLE 12c XML: Extract value from XML string using EXTRACTVALUE

Tags: xml, oracle

Id appreciate your help on this one..

I have an XML string contained in an XMLType and Im trying to extract a single value from it.. I've spent ages now based on lots of online research, but without success...

the string held in l_resp_xml (xmltype) is:

```
<ns1:validateAccountResponse 
xmlns:ns1="https://ws.hyphen.co.za/accountvalidation2">
<return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:type="tns:WebService_AccountValidation_Response">
     <reference xsi:type="xsd:string">TLPM165U2876100975</reference>
     <branchCode xsi:type="xsd:string">187646</branchCode>
     <bankName xsi:type="xsd:string">NED:NEDBANK LTD RSA</bankName>
     <branchName xsi:type="xsd:string">NEDBANK BRITS</branchName>
     <accountNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">00000002876100975</accountNumber>
     <accountType xsi:type="xsd:string">2</accountType>
     <errorCode xsi:type="xsd:string">0</errorCode>
     <resultCode xsi:type="xsd:string">0000</resultCode>
     <resultMessage xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
     <checkSum xsi:type="xsd:string">db8d375002ca1e62ab4e8696c480df12d7e10293a29ba1a0dc99868d18    aa2c7e</checkSum>
</return></ns1:validateAccountResponse>
```

And Ive tried a bunch of different ways to get the value of bankName out. The latest is simply:

```
         SELECT 
         EXTRACTVALUE(l_resp_xml, '/return/bankName')
         into l_bank_name
     FROM DUAL;
```

I've tried lots of variations, but cannot get the value from bankName (the contents of l_bank_name is always blank.. if someone could help, Id be grateful

Many Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 2):

Although `EXTRACTVALUE` has been deprecated, this would be the version with EXTRACTVALUE:

```
SELECT 
    EXTRACTVALUE(l_resp_xml, '/ns1:validateAccountResponse/return/bankName', 'xmlns:ns1="https://ws.hyphen.co.za/accountvalidation2"')
INTO l_bank_name
FROM dual;
```

But `XMLTable` or `XMLQuery` is the preferred way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

`EXTRACTVALUE` has been [deprecated for some time](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions061.htm). You should be using [XQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb_xquery.htm), in this case with a single simple path using XMLQuery; plus you need to refer to the namespace `ns1`, and you are ignoring the top-level node `validateAccountResponse`:

```
with t (l_resp_xml) as (
  select xmltype('<ns1:validateAccountResponse 
xmlns:ns1="https://ws.hyphen.co.za/accountvalidation2">
<return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:type="tns:WebService_AccountValidation_Response">
     <reference xsi:type="xsd:string">TLPM165U2876100975</reference>
     <branchCode xsi:type="xsd:string">187646</branchCode>
     <bankName xsi:type="xsd:string">NED:NEDBANK LTD RSA</bankName>
     <branchName xsi:type="xsd:string">NEDBANK BRITS</branchName>
     <accountNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">00000002876100975</accountNumber>
     <accountType xsi:type="xsd:string">2</accountType>
     <errorCode xsi:type="xsd:string">0</errorCode>
     <resultCode xsi:type="xsd:string">0000</resultCode>
     <resultMessage xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
     <checkSum xsi:type="xsd:string">db8d375002ca1e62ab4e8696c480df12d7e10293a29ba1a0dc99868d18    aa2c7e</checkSum>
</return></ns1:validateAccountResponse>') from dual
)
SELECT XMLQuery('declare namespace ns1 = "https://ws.hyphen.co.za/accountvalidation2"; (::)
    /ns1:validateAccountResponse/return/bankName/text()'
  PASSING l_resp_xml RETURNING CONTENT) AS bankName
FROM t;

BANKNAME                                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NED:NEDBANK LTD RSA
```

Or with your PL/SQL value:

```
SELECT CAST(XMLQuery('declare namespace ns1 = "https://ws.hyphen.co.za/accountvalidation2"; (::)
    /ns1:validateAccountResponse/return/bankName/text()'
  PASSING l_resp_xml RETURNING CONTENT) AS VARCHAR2(30))
INTO l_bank_name
FROM dual;
```

You could also use an XMLTable to extract multiple values more easily, particularly when you're getting multiple XMLType values from rows in a table:

```
with t (l_resp_xml) as (
  select xmltype('<ns1:validateAccountResponse 
xmlns:ns1="https://ws.hyphen.co.za/accountvalidation2">
<return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:type="tns:WebService_AccountValidation_Response">
     <reference xsi:type="xsd:string">TLPM165U2876100975</reference>
     <branchCode xsi:type="xsd:string">187646</branchCode>
     <bankName xsi:type="xsd:string">NED:NEDBANK LTD RSA</bankName>
     <branchName xsi:type="xsd:string">NEDBANK BRITS</branchName>
     <accountNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">00000002876100975</accountNumber>
     <accountType xsi:type="xsd:string">2</accountType>
     <errorCode xsi:type="xsd:string">0</errorCode>
     <resultCode xsi:type="xsd:string">0000</resultCode>
     <resultMessage xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
     <checkSum xsi:type="xsd:string">db8d375002ca1e62ab4e8696c480df12d7e10293a29ba1a0dc99868d18    aa2c7e</checkSum>
</return></ns1:validateAccountResponse>') from dual
)
SELECT x.reference, x.bankname, x.branchCode
FROM t
CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
  XMLNAMESPACES('https://ws.hyphen.co.za/accountvalidation2' as "ns1"),
  '/ns1:validateAccountResponse/return'
  PASSING t.l_resp_xml
  COLUMNS reference VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'reference',
    bankName VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'bankName',
    branchCode NUMBER PATH 'branchCode'
) x;

REFERENCE            BANKNAME                       BRANCHCODE
-------------------- ------------------------------ ----------
TLPM165U2876100975   NED:NEDBANK LTD RSA                187646
```

Comment: Thanks Alex,  The perils of finding sample code on the Net... Does this mean that Extract is also depreciated? Im using            
                l_resp_xml := xmltype.createxml(l_clob_response);

                -- Clean SOAP header
       
         SELECT extract(l_resp_xml
                              ,'Envelope/Body/node()'
                              ,l_namespace_soap)
                  INTO l_resp_xml
                  FROM dual;       to retrieve the XML fragment from the SOAP Envelope..

Comment: [Yes, it is](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions068.htm).  You can use XQuery for that too. Or just include the Envelope/Body and SOAP namespace along with the return in a single XQuery.

Comment: @RichardLegge - [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32443437/266304) is extracting data from a SOAP envelope; very similar idea and shows the two namespaces.

Comment: Great stuff thanks. Just got that working.. Thanks a lot for your input. appreciated.