# oracle sql: how to read XML and how to get value

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I'm new to oracle,i have XML column in table,in that column data is in XML format

i.e,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<charge textid="dacebab6-962e-3-b23d70eef85a" id="parse"><properties/></charge>
```

Now i want get only **textid**, so how to get textid thorough **SQL** query.

i tried **select XMLSequence(Extract(x,'/charge/textid/text()')) from emp_datails;** but not working.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "not working".  Include a stack trace and error message(s).

Comment: @Jim Garrison: it display **ora-06553 pls-306 wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ogc_x'**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORACLE 12c XML: Extract value from XML string using EXTRACTVALUE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518415/oracle-12c-xml-extract-value-from-xml-string-using-extractvalue)

Comment: @Florin Ghita: my question is different. how to decide it is duplicate,first resolve my issue after i will agree.

Comment: Noel's example seems to work. what version of Oracle do you have?

Comment: i tried Noel's example but it is not working, i'm using Oracle 10g.

Comment: @Florin Ghita... please change negative marks for my question.

Comment: For me it's working. His answer addresses what you asked. Also it is asked  and has response in that question. You should be more specific in what is not working. The query in the question is wrong.

Comment: I didn't downvote you... The question is visible on the site for many users.

Comment: Maybe you have a problem with CTEs. Try this form of the query: `select EXTRACTVALUE(y, '/charge/properties') properties, EXTRACTVALUE(y, '/charge/@textid') textid
from
  (SELECT xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<charge textid="dacebab6-962e-3-b23d70eef85a" id="parse"> 
 <properties> asdd </properties>  
 </charge>') as y
  FROM dual
  );`

Comment: @Florin Ghita.. i tried your query it is executed but how to pass my column,i mean this is **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <charge textid="dacebab6-962e-3-b23d70eef85a" id="parse"> <properties> asdd </properties> </charge>** column data, my column name is **XML** and table name is **emp_details**.

Comment: Ok, that's poor. `select EXTRACTVALUE(a.xml, '/charge/@textid') textid, a.* from emp_details a;` ?

Comment: it throws error like **ORA-00932 inconsistent datatypes expected - got -**

Comment: if the type of the column is varchar2 then use `xmltype(a.xml)` instead of `a.xml`;

Comment: in my table  **xml** column datatype is **LONG**

Comment: In order to use xmltype you must have data in Clob datatype. Converting LONG to Clob is another problem. Long is no longer recommended from Oracle 8i. Get rid of it as soos as you can.

Answer (score 1):

Use EXTRACTVALUE.

```
select EXTRACTVALUE(x,'/charge/@textid') from emp_datails;
```

Example:

```
WITH x(y) AS
  (SELECT xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<charge textid="dacebab6-962e-3-b23d70eef85a" id="parse">asdd<properties/>asd</charge>')
  FROM dual
  )
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(y, '/charge/@textid') textid FROM x;

TEXTID
----------
dacebab6-962e-3-b23d70eef85a
```

Comment: how to execute your query, i mean i tried **WITH x(y) AS
  (SELECT xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<charge textid="dacebab6-962e-3-b23d70eef85a" id="parse">asdd<properties/>asd</charge>')
  FROM dual
  )** but it's not execute

Answer (score 0):

with this statement you can extract the textid:

```
-- Your data
with data as
 (select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <charge textid="dacebab6-962e-3-b23d70eef85a" id="parse"><properties/></charge>' as xmlval
    from dual)

 (SELECT attr_value
    FROM data d,
         xmltable('.' PASSING xmltype(d.xmlval) COLUMNS attr_value
                  VARCHAR2(30) PATH '/charge/@textid'));
```

Comment: i tried you query **with data as
 (select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <charge textid="dacebab6-962e-3-b23d70eef85a" id="parse"><properties/></charge>' as xmlval
    from dual)** but not execute in my scratch pad

Comment: what is meaning of **with data as**?

Comment: try `with data as (select 'hello' from dual) (select * from data)` to understand it. In this case it's only a statement to prepare test data, replace it by your table.

Comment: you have to call the whole statement `with data as
 (select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <charge textid="dacebab6-962e-3-b23d70eef85a" id="parse"><properties/></charge>' as xmlval
    from dual)

 (SELECT attr_value
    FROM data d,
         xmltable('.' PASSING xmltype(d.xmlval) COLUMNS attr_value
                  VARCHAR2(30) PATH '/charge/@textid'));`

Comment: :oracle 10g. I tried your query it is executed successfully but out put is not displaying. only it displaying **The SQL has been executed successfully**.

Comment: may be data is save in other place?