# xml nodes with special characters

Tags: oracle

I have testing.xml file like this:

```
<ROWSET>
<ROW_DATA:TYPE>
<ID>1</ID>
<TEXT>This is some text</TEXT>
</ROW_DATA:TYPE>
<ROW_DATA:TYPE>
<ID>2</ID>
<TEXT>This is some more text</TEXT>
</ROW_DATA:TYPE>
<ROW_DATA:TYPE>
<ID>3</ID>
<TEXT>This is some other text</TEXT>
</ROW_DATA:TYPE>
<ROW_DATA:TYPE>
<ID>4</ID>
<TEXT>This is also some text</TEXT>
</ROW_DATA:TYPE>
</ROWSET>
```

I loaded this testing.xml file into the table test_xml:

```
INSERT INTO test_xml VALUES( 
xmltype(bfilename('TESTING','testing.xml'),nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')));
commit;
```

After that, I tried to write the code to fetch the data from xml table:

```
select grp1.* 
from 
test_xml t
,xmltable('//ROWSET'
          passing t.SYS_NC_ROWINFO$
          columns row_1     xmltype   path  '/ROWSET/ROW_DATA:TYPE'
         ) grp0

,xmltable('/ROW_DATA:TYPE'
          passing grp0.row_1
          columns ID_1    NUMBER(10)  PATH 'ID'
                  ,TEXT_1    VARCHAR2(40)  PATH 'TEXT'
         ) grp1 
;
```

Finally, it came up with an error message:

```
ORA-19228: XPST0008 - undeclared identifier: prefix 'ROW_DATA' local-name 'ROW_DATA:TYPE'
19228. 00000 -  "XP0008 - undeclared identifier: prefix '%s' local-name '%s'"
*Cause:    The given identifier refers to either a type name, function name, namespace prefix, or variable name that is not defined in the static context.
*Action:   Fix the expression to remove the identifier, or declare the appropriate variable, type, function or namespace.
Error at Line: 17 Column: 2
```

So, in one of the XML nodes, they have special characters (:) which I am unable to handle. Can someone help me on this please?

Real XML file (getting from web-services) is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <MultiSpeakMsgHeader AppName="CD" AppVersion="3.0" CSUnits="feet" Company="xxxxx" LastSent="123455" ObjectsRemaining="1" xmlns="http://www.multispeak.org/Version_3.0"/>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <GetReadingsByDateResponse>
         <GetReadingsByDateResult>
            <meterRead>
               <meterNo>10227</meterNo>
               <deviceID>2</deviceID>
               <readingDate>2016-12-18T06:15:00.339Z</readingDate>
               <posKWh>85893</posKWh>
               <kW>2.8018</kW>
               <phase>AB</phase>
               <readingValues>
                  <readingValue>
                     <units>kWh</units>
                     <value>85892.586</value>
                     <readingValueType>Energy</readingValueType>
                     <dateTime>2016-12-18T06:15:00.339Z</dateTime>
                  </readingValue>
                  <readingValue>
                     <units>kW</units>
                     <value>2.504</value>
                     <readingValueType>Current demand</readingValueType>
                     <dateTime>2016-12-18T06:15:00.339Z</dateTime>
                  </readingValue>
                  <readingValue>
                     <units>kW</units>
                     <value>2.8018</value>
                     <readingValueType>Max demand</readingValueType>
                     <dateTime>2016-12-18T06:15:00.339Z</dateTime>
                  </readingValue>
                  <readingValue>
                     <units>V</units>
                     <value>244.1</value>
                     <readingValueType>Current Voltage</readingValueType>
                     <dateTime>2016-12-18T06:15:00.339Z</dateTime>
                  </readingValue>
                  <readingValue>
                     <units>V</units>
                     <value>244.1</value>
                     <readingValueType>Current Voltage Phase A</readingValueType>
                     <dateTime>2016-12-18T06:15:00.339Z</dateTime>
                  </readingValue>
                  <readingValue>
                     <units>V</units>
                     <value>0.3</value>
                     <readingValueType>Current Voltage Phase B</readingValueType>
                     <dateTime>2016-12-18T06:15:00.339Z</dateTime>
                  </readingValue>
               </readingValues>
            </meterRead>
         </GetReadingsByDateResult>
      </GetReadingsByDateResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: What is generating that XML?

Comment: this is the sample XML file that i shared here for an easy explanation of the error that i am facing.

Comment: It looks like the sample is coming from `dbms_xmlgen` with a strange `setRowTag()` value. As far as I'm aware you can't have a colon as part of the actual node name, as it indicates one of the things mentioned in the error message. Does your real XML have a namespace (`xmlns` values embedded in any of the nodes)? It isn't clear if your real XML looks like this or if you've hidden the real problem by oversimplifying. If you can't share your real XML, please at least use something that is structurally the same...

Comment: OK understood, let me share the real XML file

Comment: OK, what about you real query? You probably just need to declare the namespace (as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32443437/266304), though yours is called SOAP-ENV rather than soapenv).

Comment: ok let me try that, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error is because your query isn't declaring the namespace, in either XMLTable call. The XML has the namespace declared in the `SOAP-ENV:Envelope` node, as `xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`.

You can add a namespace declaration to your XMLTable calls, something like:

```
select grp1.* 
from 
test_xml t
,xmltable(xmlnamespaces ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope' AS "SOAP-ENV"),
          '/SOAP-ENV:Envelope'
          passing t.SYS_NC_ROWINFO$
          columns row_1     xmltype   path  'SOAP-ENV:Body'
         ) grp0
,xmltable(xmlnamespaces ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope' AS "SOAP-ENV"),
          '/SOAP-ENV:Body'
          passing grp0.row_1
          columns ID_1    NUMBER(10)  PATH 'ID'
                  ,TEXT_1    VARCHAR2(40)  PATH 'TEXT'
         ) grp1
```

Or a more useful example with your sample data:

```
select x1.meterNo,
  from_tz(to_timestamp(x1.readingDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"'), 'UTC') as readingDate,
  x2.readingValueType, x2.value, x2.units 
from test_xml t
cross join xmltable(
  xmlnamespaces ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS "SOAP-ENV"),
  '/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/GetReadingsByDateResponse/GetReadingsByDateResult/meterRead'
  passing t.SYS_NC_ROWINFO$
  columns meterNo number path 'meterNo',
    readingDate varchar2(24) path 'readingDate',
    readingValues xmltype path  'readingValues'
) x1
cross join xmltable(
  '/readingValues/readingValue'
  passing x1.readingValues
  columns readingValueType varchar2(30) path 'readingValueType',
    value number path 'value',
    units varchar2(3) path 'units'
) x2;

   METERNO READINGDATE                      READINGVALUETYPE                    VALUE UNI
---------- -------------------------------- ------------------------------ ---------- ---
     10227 18-DEC-16 06.15.00.339000000 UTC Energy                          85892.586 kWh
     10227 18-DEC-16 06.15.00.339000000 UTC Current demand                      2.504 kW 
     10227 18-DEC-16 06.15.00.339000000 UTC Max demand                         2.8018 kW 
     10227 18-DEC-16 06.15.00.339000000 UTC Current Voltage                     244.1 V  
     10227 18-DEC-16 06.15.00.339000000 UTC Current Voltage Phase A             244.1 V  
     10227 18-DEC-16 06.15.00.339000000 UTC Current Voltage Phase B                .3 V
```

Notice that in this case you don't need the namespace to be declared in the second XMLTable, as the nodes you're referencing there aren't prefixed with SOAP-ENV.

---

You could cheat and use wildcards:

```
...
from test_xml t
cross join xmltable(
  '/*:Envelope/*:Body/GetReadingsByDateResponse/GetReadingsByDateResult/meterRead'
  passing t.SYS_NC_ROWINFO$
...
```

or ignore the prefixed nodes if you don't need any data directly from those, only their children:

```
...
from test_xml t
cross join xmltable(
  '//meterRead'
  passing t.SYS_NC_ROWINFO$
...
```

but I think it's better to be explicit.

Comment: Perfect.. Thanks a lot for the solution and the useful information.